# Flutter Socket connection, multiple lines mixing up

Tags: flutter, sockets, websocket

I am trying to implement a websocket connection in flutter so that 2 mobile phones in the same network can communicate with each other. The websocket connection is established and works perfectly. However, I have a problem when I send several data at once. As I send several streams with different information one after the other, these streams get mixed up. This happens because they arrive at the receiving device at the same time and cannot be differentiated there. Is there a simple way to prevent this?

Currently I am Trying to Indicate a new String by Ascii Null but this wont help me with that problem.

The code responsible for sending the data is as follows.

```
void sendData(CurrentUser user) {
    socket?.writeln('name|${user.name}\u0000');
    socket?.writeln("amount|${user.objects.length}\u0000");
    for(var object in user.objects) {
      socket?.writeln("object|ObjectInfoHere\u0000");
    }
  }
```

The only solution I could think of would be to implement this in a similar way to the handshake in TCP. However, I think this is a little too complicated for this situation and hope that there is a simpler, more efficient solution.